# Silverlight Data and Element Binding

Tags: c#, silverlight, binding

What is the difference between these two?

```
DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=listBoxStudents}

DataContext="{Binding ElementName=listBoxStudents, Path=SelectedItem}
```

In Apress Pro Silverlight 4,  the second example is a simple element to element binding.
The First example is related to Data binding, I think.

In my  app they do the same.
Can someone clarify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two lines you present have exactly the same meaning.  Both of them specify a binding to the `SelectedItem` property of an element whose name is `listBoxStudents`.

If the `Path` property comes first in your `{Binding ...}`, you can miss off the `Path=` part.  Other than that, the order of properties in a `{Binding ...}` is unimportant.